# What is the equivalent of ruby script/about in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the equivalent of `ruby script/about` in Rails 3? I tried `rails about` and `rails help` and could not find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just dug into an old Rails 2 project to find out what script/info actually did - but it wasn't there. Are you sure it was part of rails core? If so - what sort of output did you used to get?

Comment: there is not such a command, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to say 'ruby script/about' which I updated above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `rake about` should give you the same information. It works for me on Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html has detailed info on the commands available in Rails.